# How to add dynamic data to an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Given static data, how can I add dynamic data using JSON and REST and how will I get data on the server please give me any solution please

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/

Comment: My listview is an expandable listview

Answer (score 0):

Filling dynamic data to expandable listview is almost similar like static data. Just collect your dynamic data and store it in an ArrayList and load it similarly how you added static data

In order to fetch data from server please follow the steps here

first compile you dependency in `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

Now create a class named `Appcontroller` which extends `Application` and add this and import those api which is showing red line

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();


    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;


    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        int socketTimeOut = 60000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        req.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

    public static String getDate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        return formatedDate;
    }
}
```

after that, to get data from server use this methods
add these two in your class level

```
Response.Listener<String> jsonResponse;
Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
```

Now, initialize those within `onCreate`

```
jsonResponse = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("Response", response);

        //parseData(response); and store in arraylist to show it in expandablelistview


    }
};

errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch Data from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
};
if (ServerConfig.isNetworkOnline(SplashScreen.this)) {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "your server link", serverResponse, errorListener) {
    };
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(strReq);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

if problem let me know and dont forget to add `Appcontroller` to your 
manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"..../>
```

Comment: i am using the eclipse

Comment: you can download volley jar file from here

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.17

or you can also download it from here 
http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/10/

or you can follow the process from here its quite understandable here
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/